# Logic vs Metalogic

Tags: logic

In Hunter's "Metalogic," the author defines metalogic as a theory of sentences used to express truths of logic, and goes onto explain model theory and proof theory.

When reading books teaching classical first order logic itself, it seems that there are parts of the text that seem to be "metalogic," such as discussion of the symbols and their meanings in analogy to reasoning in natural language.

Would it be fair to say that there's metalogic/metatheory in these first order logic texts without calling attention to itself as metalogic, or is there a more clear cut distinction?

Comment: There is "metatheory" in every mathematical text, or rather, there are parts that would become that if they were to be formalized. Natural language does not make such distinctions, it is technicality [introduced by Tarski](https://iep.utm.edu/liar-paradox/#SH3b) for formal systems, and that is what the texts are written in. They are not "calling attention" to it because there is nothing to call attention to.

Comment: I second @Conifold's comment. How do you present a topic in logic without talking about it? And if you talk about it, then that's meta-logic. Well, in the lenient sense of the word; it's *regarding logic*, but it isn't *logic regarding logic*, unless it is formalized (as Conifold mentioned).

Comment: Indeed the situation is exactly same as physics vs metaphysics, there're always implicit meta-language of physics known from antiquity as metaphysics talk about and express truth of sentences of the language of any physics theory...

Comment: Basically, every textbook dealing with "mathematical logic" is written in "meta-logic"...

Comment: The specifications for the formal language are written not in the formal language itself but in plain English: the meta-language.

Comment: See the post [Distinction between language and metalanguage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159383/is-the-distinction-between-language-and-metalanguage-strictly-parallel-the-disti)

Comment: Thanks, all. I think my confusion came from this part of the book, "We use English, supplemented by special symbolism for our metalanguage." I guess the author is using a more relaxed definition than @Conifold since this book is targeted at those without math background.

Comment: The issue is quite simple... consider a usual mathematics textbook regarding e.g. real analysis. The "subject" of the book is real numbers with their properties and the book is written in "usual" mathematical jargon: natural language (e.g. English) plus symbols. Mathematical logic is the mathematical study of formal languages: formal languages (e.g. propositional calculus) are the subject of the book while the book is written in "usual" mathematical jargon: natural language plus symbols (the meta-language).